# Flexbox combined with vertical overflow is not working correctly

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox, overflow

I have an issue that has been bugging me for hours and I just can figure out how to fix it.

I have created a card (similar to the ones in Bootstrap). I have given it a fixed height. That's all fine.

However, inside the card. I have a div, with a class called "transaction-lines". In it, you have several individual lines inside the div. There could be 1-50.

What I am trying to do is to get the overflow-y working, so that if the height of the "transaction-lines" div is bigger than the fixed height of the card, it will trigger the scroll mode (overflow-y: scroll).

If you look at it now, it doesn't trigger scroll mode correctly. If you remove a few comment lines, from the fiddle, it will look normal.

https://codepen.io/DocRow10/pen/MWQPLzo

```
<div class="test-card style-one main-details" style="height: 34vh;">
    <div class="card-main-content">
        <div class="card-main-content-container">
            <div class="content-container">
                <section class="tab-section">
                    <div class="transaction-lines">
                        <div class="line">
                            <div class="indicator">
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Test Comment Line
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="line">
                            <div class="indicator">
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Test Comment Line
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="line">
                            <div class="indicator">
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Test Comment Line
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="line">
                            <div class="indicator">
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Test Comment Line
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="line">
                            <div class="indicator">
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Test Comment Line
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="line">
                            <div class="indicator">
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Test Comment Line
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="line">
                            <div class="indicator">
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Test Comment Line
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer-container">
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button class="primary-button">Button</button>
            <button class="primary-button">Button</button><button class="primary-button">Button</button><button
                class="primary-button">Button</button><button class="primary-button">Button</button><button
                class="primary-button">Button</button><button class="primary-button">Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out myself, partially thanks to @mdurchholz above, but it was the .card-main-content itself that was overflowing, not the .transaction-lines. The child element (.card-main-content) to the parent you've set the height on (.test-card), is the one that needs the overflow property and not one of it's children.

To resolve this, I had to make the .content-container a direct child of the .test-card and then apply the overflow proprety there. Added flex: 1 to the .content-container, so it would stretch the remaining vertical space of the .test-card. If you have a lot of content in the .content-container, scrolling will now activate, without moving any of the other content, which is exactly what I needed.

Flexbox wasn't relevant to this issue.

Thanks and I hope this is helpful to someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think the instructions below will give you what you're looking for:

1. Remove height property from .test-card
2. Add max-height property to .card-main-content (ex: max-height: 150px;)
3. Add the following CSS to .card-main-content:

   overflow: hidden;
   overflow-y: auto;
4. Remove CSS from .tab-section

The idea is that you wan the height of your scrollable area to be defined. You don't set a height on a container and add a scrollable area inside it.

Comment: Is it possible to get this working inside the .tab-section? The reason I'm asking is because there may be multiple .tab-sections in a page and some might need the scrolling ability and others won't. In other words, could I add the scroll to the .transaction-lines or a parent div (if I created a new one)?